# How to respect quantitative nature of discrete/group variables in R ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to do a plot with R ggplot2 functions to highlight relations between a categorical X and a continuous Y variable. But my categorical variable is quantitative (e.g integers) and I would like my plots to respect the position suggested by the quantitative value of X.

Imagine the following dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(Category=sample(c(1, 2, 5), 1000, replace = T)) %>%
  mutate(Value=Category+rnorm(1000))
```

The easiest boxplot would be :

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=as.factor(Category), y=Value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(x="Category")
```

[image]

But what I would like is :

```
add_row(df, Category=3:4, Value=NA) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=as.factor(Category), y=Value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(x="Category")
```

[image]

Do you know any proper way to achieve that beyond the ugly trick above that is not really scalable? Because we can imagine many boxplots. Or even the case in which my categories are decimal values (with of course a limited number of categories). All in all, my wish is to be able to distribute my boxplots along the x-axis according to the quantitative value of the categories. The same question could apply to barplot instead of boxplots of course...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Keep the category as numeric and add `group = Category` inside the `aes`

Comment: I tried "x" and "group" separately and not together. So simple that I don't understand how I couldn't have found the answer on my own... 
Thanks!

Comment: Perfectly. It's even an absolute duplicate that I regret not having found before asking my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @camille, you should write:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x=Category, y=Value, group = Category)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(x="Category")
```

[image]